# Passing values through URL or POST variable instead?

Tags: php, session, post

I'm implementing a message system (private messaging, if you will) and I'd like to be able to display the list of messages a user has by a text link so I don't need a button to open it. The message_id (unique value in the databse) would be passed through the URL. (something like www.example.com/message/view/16).Assuming I check to make sure the session of the userid matches the userid that the message is sent to, is this OK? To make it safer I could just append a random number and set that as as session, and then just check for that upon viewing.

Should I forget this idea and just stick with a submit button to view the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A POST request would not provide any more safety than a GET request: any half-decent web debugging tool can forge POST requests. You should simply never trust user-input data. Always double-check authorizations for safety!

That said, [`GET` request semantics match what you're trying to do here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

The HTTP standard says that a `GET` request should be repeatable without any non-trivial consequence. For instance, it's adequate to *view* data with a GET request (and possibly do small things like incrementing a counter, since these are pretty trivial consequences). In fact, `GET`and `HEAD` are the two request methods that are considered "safe".

On the other hand, `POST` requests are expected to have non-trivial consequences, like sending a message or placing an order. Stuff that you don't want to perform twice accidentally. Most browsers these days also respect this by warning users when reloading a page would cause a `POST` request to be performed again.

Comment: Should I still append a random string to the end, set session, and match the session/string upon viewing?

Comment: @user1104854, I suggest cookies for storing session IDs. The random string would prevent people from legitimately saving the URL. What you really want is to make sure the person reading the message really is the person the message belongs to: you should do that by verifying that the identity of the person is the same as the message's recipient, and you should not base that on additional data passed by the browser. (Also keep in mind that _even cookies_ can be faked.)

Comment: That sounds like it'll work just fine. It's not like I'm storing bank account information, so cookies will do the job. Thanks!

Comment: @user1104854 I would not apply random string to the end of the URL, as it would prevent the user from bookmarking the page perhaps.  You would need to verify that the user has a valid login (probably via data in `$_SESSION`).  If your concern here is over cross-site request forgery (typically mitigated with session token matching hidden form token), then I don't get the concern in this case in that you are not going to be changing any data on the server with this request. The main attack vector here would seem to be session hijacking, which might be mitigated by checking IP address in session.

Comment: @user1104854 And by using things like `session_regenerate_id(true)` on each page load to swap out the session id.

Answer (score 1):

Using GET values for viewing messages is much better idea, because assuming a user stays logged in, it would allow them to bookmark messages, etc.